# Migrate from android studio to vscode

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I’ve played around with Visual Studio Code a few times, Its light weight and  there’s a clean interface. Android Studio  heavier, and compicated.How can i move flutter project to vscode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updating the extension**

1. Click the Extensions button in the Side Bar.
2. If the Flutter extension is shown with an available update, click the update button and then the reload button.
3. Restart VS Code.

**Opening a project from existing source code**

1. Click File > Open from the main IDE window.
2. Browse to the directory holding your existing Flutter source code files.
3. Click Open.

**Run app**

- Click **Run** > **Start Without Debugging**  if you want to run app without breakpoints
- Click **Run** > **Start Without Debugging**  if you want to run app with breakpoints

Comment: @flutter app: I completely agree with you that "Android Studio heavier, and complicated"  Personally, I much prefer developing Flutter apps in MS VSCode.  Xuann Thucc gave you a great answer: it's really pretty much as simple as he describes.  Please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" his answer.  See also [Flutter documentation: Visual Studio Code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code)